# Kali linux iwlwifi-7265D.11-12.ucode

Tags: linux, debian, kali-linux

Hello everyone,
           I'm trying to figure out how to fix this without reinstalling the operating system. I know their fixes for this, I have been on many different sites looking at this problem. I cannot use Aircrack in the tutorial i was working on and i think this is the reason. Anyway my wireless card is an Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC-7265 and need to install i guess the iwlwifi-7265D-11.ucode and iwlwifi-7265D.12.ucode drivers? I have added:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian sid main non-free
```

this to the /etc/apt/sources.list but when i do the upgrade it wants to upgrade 594 things and I don't know if that will effect whats on the system all ready. Is there a way to just upgrade the iwlwifi using this or can i install them manually? I would prefer manually only cause I could undo what I did unlike trying to undo 595 things. Any help or advice is gratefully appreciated. Thank you so much in advance!

Ok so i have tried:

```
apt-get update firmware-iwlwifi
```

and it says its the newest version and still no luck.

```
root@Kali:~# modinfo iwlwifi | grep firmware
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3165-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-10.ucode
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error            
(default true) (bool)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: 
false   - needs lots of memory) (bool)
```

Comment: Can you tell me where you read you need the 7265**D** firmware? I have the same card as you (under Kubuntu) and, while I do have one of the two firmware files you mention, the driver itself, `iwlwifi` does not mention it among the possible firmware files it can use, `modinfo iwlwifi | grep firmware`. So, if there exists a newer version of the driver which does use such firmware **and** this solves your problem, I can teach you how to install it, but I would rather make sure, first, that  I am not leading you on a wild goose chase.

Comment: Np when i installed the system that poped up that it was missing those files. And everytime i boot it says failed to load iwlwifi-7265D.11.ucode and iwlwifi-7265D.12.ucode let me check the script real quick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a mismatch: on the one hand,

> everytime i boot it says failed to load iwlwifi-7265D.11.ucode and iwlwifi-7265D.12.ucode

but on the other hand,

```
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode
```

but no mention of `7265D-11.ucode` nor of `7265D-12.ucode`. So you need to install the latest driver, then update your firmware.

Download the [newest Linux kernel backports from here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/11/20/backports-20151120.tar.gz). Now go to the directory where you downloaded the package, and issue:

```
tar xvfz backports-20151120.tar.gz
cd backports-20151120
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

Now you can check with `modinfo iwlwifi | grep firmware` that your driver is compatible with the newest version of the firmware available, 7265D-13-ucode. However, this is **not** in `/lib/firmware`, you will have to download it from [here](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi). The version you want is [this one](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-7265-ucode-25.30.13.0.tgz), untar the file and place the firmware files (`*.ucode`) in `/lib/firmware`. You may wish to change the name of `iwlwifi-7265.13.ucode` to something else to make sure the **D** version is loaded. Reboot and you should be done.

Comment: Do I need to change iwlwifi-7265D.13.ucode or iwlwifi-7265.13.ucode to something else?

Comment: @DakotaMiller My bad, just edited the answer: change 7265.13.ucode to something else.

Comment: @ MariusMatutiae Is it ok that it says failed to load iwlwifi-7265D.14 though 19.ucode now lol.

Comment: @DakotaMiller LOL There is nothing more `current` than this driver in Linux. Also, the Wireless Kernel page I referred above does **not** have anything above 7265D15. So I think we should start questioning the script sending these messages, don't you think? Are you able to put your card in monitor mode? Are you able to inject code? If so, never mind the error messages.

Comment: I'm going to give it a try tomorrow. I have 2 hours till i have to take kids to school. I will let you know about the moniter mode and injection packets. I think your right lol. And thank you again for your help!

Comment: @ MariusMatutiae Hey it works just fine. Thank you for your help!

Comment: +1 for this solution that I took so long to find. I had a compile error though `/lxdialog/check-lxdialog.sh: cc: not found` that I could sort out by specifying my compiler in the Makefile. Adding `CC = /usr/bin/gcc-5; export CC` in the Makefile script did the trick.