# trouble getting wifi adapter to work in kali linux 2.0

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers, kali-linux

I am trying to get a WIFI adapter to work in Kali Linux 2.0. The WIFI adapter is a Alfa awus051nh v2. The chipset is rt3572. I was able to get the driver off the disc and move it to /lib/firmware then rebooted. Nothing happened, there was still no interface then just to make sure it was compatible I double checked and as far as I know the rt3572 driver is supported. Here is what I have done so far:

```
root@Kali:~/Downloads# lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0747 Genesys Logic, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0457:10c6 Silicon Integrated Systems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b414 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0b05:17fd ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 148f:3572 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT3572       
Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

After I saw it was being recognized I checked to see if it had an interface and it didn't. So I got the driver off the disc (RT2870.bin) that came with it and moved it into the /lib/firmware and rebooted. Nothing! I unplugged the device and plug it back in then did the dmesg results:

```
[ 3163.584223] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[ 3163.784502] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=148f,    
idProduct=3572
[ 3163.784507] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2,  
SerialNumber=3
[ 3163.784509] usb 1-2: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
[ 3163.784511] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Ralink
[ 3163.784513] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 1.0
[ 3164.795381] rt2x00lib: disagrees about version of symbol  
ieee80211_register_hw
[ 3164.795384] rt2x00lib: Unknown symbol ieee80211_register_hw (err -22)
[ 3164.795394] rt2x00lib: disagrees about version of symbol   
ieee80211_get_hdrlen_from_skb
[ 3164.795395] rt2x00lib: Unknown symbol ieee80211_get_hdrlen_from_skb   
(err -22)
[ 3164.795400] rt2x00lib: disagrees about version of symbol   
ieee80211_wake_queue
[ 3164.795401] rt2x00lib: Unknown symbol ieee80211_wake_queue (err -22)
[ 3164.795409] rt2x00lib: disagrees about version of symbol  
ieee80211_get_buffered_bc
[ 3164.795410] rt2x00lib: Unknown symbol ieee80211_get_buffered_bc (err  
-22)
[ 3164.795416] rt2x00lib: disagrees about version of symbol  
wiphy_rfkill_set_hw_state
[ 3164.795417] rt2x00lib: Unknown symbol wiphy_rfkill_set_hw_state (err  
-22)
[ 3164.795425] rt2x00lib: disagrees about version of symbol  
ieee80211_queue_delayed_work
[ 3164.795426] rt2x00lib: Unknown symbol ieee80211_queue_delayed_work  
(err -22)
[ 3164.795429] rt2x00lib: disagrees about version of symbol  
wiphy_rfkill_stop_polling
[ 3164.795430] rt2x00lib: Unknown symbol wiphy_rfkill_stop_polling (err  
-22)
[ 3164.795432] rt2x00lib: disagrees about version of symbol  
ieee80211_ctstoself_get
[ 3164.795433] rt2x00lib: Unknown symbol ieee80211_ctstoself_get (err -22)
[ 3164.795472] rt2x00lib: Unknown symbol ieee80211_rx (err 0)
[ 3164.795486] rt2x00lib: Unknown symbol  
ieee80211_iterate_active_interfaces (err 0)
[ 3164.795489] rt2x00lib: disagrees about version of symbol  
ieee80211_free_txskb
[ 3164.795490] rt2x00lib: Unknown symbol ieee80211_free_txskb (err -22)
[ 3164.795495] rt2x00lib: disagrees about version of symbol  
ieee80211_tx_status
[ 3164.795496] rt2x00lib: Unknown symbol ieee80211_tx_status (err -22)
[ 3164.795499] rt2x00lib: disagrees about version of symbol  
ieee80211_stop_queue
[ 3164.795500] rt2x00lib: Unknown symbol ieee80211_stop_queue (err -22)
[ 3164.795503] rt2x00lib: disagrees about version of symbol  
ieee80211_stop_queues
[ 3164.795504] rt2x00lib: Unknown symbol ieee80211_stop_queues (err -22)
[ 3164.795509] rt2x00lib: disagrees about version of symbol  
wiphy_rfkill_start_polling
[ 3164.795510] rt2x00lib: Unknown symbol wiphy_rfkill_start_polling (err  
-22)
[ 3164.795512] rt2x00lib: disagrees about version of symbol  
ieee80211_iterate_active_interfaces_atomic
[ 3164.795513] rt2x00lib: Unknown symbol  
ieee80211_iterate_active_interfaces_atomic (err -22)
[ 3164.795523] rt2x00lib: disagrees about version of symbol  
ieee80211_unregister_hw
[ 3164.795524] rt2x00lib: Unknown symbol ieee80211_unregister_hw (err -22)
[ 3164.795527] rt2x00lib: disagrees about version of symbol  
ieee80211_beacon_get_tim
[ 3164.795528] rt2x00lib: Unknown symbol ieee80211_beacon_get_tim (err  
-22)
[ 3164.795531] rt2x00lib: disagrees about version of symbol  
ieee80211_rts_get
[ 3164.795532] rt2x00lib: Unknown symbol ieee80211_rts_get (err -22)
[ 3164.795538] rt2x00lib: disagrees about version of symbol  
ieee80211_queue_work
[ 3164.795539] rt2x00lib: Unknown symbol ieee80211_queue_work (err -22)
```

So thinking it was still a driver problem I then downloaded from http://www.mediatek.com/en/downloads1/downloads/  the latest driver they had for it but again ran into a problem untarring it:

```
root@Kali:~/Downloads# tar xvjf   
DPO_RT5572_LinuxSTA_2.6.1.3_20121022.tar.bz2 

bzip2: Compressed file ends unexpectedly;
perhaps it is corrupted?  *Possible* reason follows.
bzip2: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Input file = (stdin), output file = (stdout)

It is possible that the compressed file(s) have become corrupted.
You can use the -tvv option to test integrity of such files.

You can use the `bzip2recover' program to attempt to recover
data from undamaged sections of corrupted files.

tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Any help would be great!!!! Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I already gave you the solution to this kind of problems, here http://superuser.com/questions/1007970/kali-linux-iwlwifi-7265d-11-12-ucode All you have to do is to modify the defconfig instruction with `make defconfig-rtlwifi`, that's all.

Comment: Ok so i did that now theres no wireless network interfaces at all. Tried ifconfig wlan0 up and error came up with no device. Same dmesg going on except for iwilwifi:0000:3b:00:0: failed to load module iwlmvm (error 256), is dynamic loading enabled?

Comment: Apologies, DM, my bad. I suggested the latest, cutting edge backport version as earlier, but this time this is not necessary. Do the same as above, except with the latest stable release, http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v4.2.6/backports-4.2.6-1.tar.xz  That ought to work.

Comment: I downloaded the latest stable release like you said then installed it. Same dmesg as what is posted. iwconfig reports no interfaces. the iwlmvm error is gone though.