# Iwlwifi drivers not found while Kali Linux Installation

Tags: linux, drivers

I am trying to make dual boot of Windows 8.1(already installed) and Linux Kali. I found file missing iwlwifi.ucode. Insert a removable media to install. I skipped the step. After installation while booting Kali it stops while loading at the same error "Iwlwifi firmware missing"

Please help me in this problem . I am using Dell Inspiron 5559-Inspiron 15 5000 Series Laptop.

Comment: [This question](http://superuser.com/questions/1007970/kali-linux-iwlwifi-7265d-11-12-ucode) looks very similar, and it has a solution. But it was so easy to find that I assume you already know about it.

Comment: my question is about installation while the question you are mentioning is about aircrack-ng more specifically

Comment: It deals with finding the driver and firmware, so it ought to be relevant. If not, searching for "iwlwifi.ucode kali missing" gives lots of other sites related to your problem.

Comment: I found Super User forum helpful in many other problems so I came here for this problem too but it seems you guys have more relevance and administration issues rather than dealing with the problems.
signing off  with regards sir. thanks for the support